# How to trigger the layout to change?

Tags: javascript, html, css, grid-layout, sticky

I've a `sticked` element which gets the `top`-alignment from current `scroll`-offset. Problem is, that the layout is not *"retriggerd"* if the space from it is free. So there stays a *ghost*-gap where the sticked element was...

http://fiddle.jshell.net/pPc4V/

The markup is pretty simple:

```
<a href="#"></a>
<a href="#"></a>
<a href="#"></a>
<a href="#"></a>
<a href="#" class="sticked"></a>
<a href="#"></a>
...
```

as well as the js:

```
var $win = $(this);
var sticked = document.querySelector('a.sticked');

$win.on('scroll', function () {
    var scrollTop = $win.scrollTop();
    sticked.style.top = scrollTop + 'px';

    // $win.resize();
});
```

...and the css looks good so far:

```
a {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 90px;
    height: 90px;
    background: deepskyblue;
}

.sticked {
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: tomato;
}
```

I tried to trigger the `resize`-event on scroll (as you see above uncommented), but no success! Any ideas, how to retrigger the layout so that the free-gap is filled with the next floated element?

## Update

To clarify what I mean I made a simple image-timelime:

**Step 1**
[image: Step 1]

**Step 2**
[image: Step 2]

**Step 3**
[image: Step 3]

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you are setting position fixed on an element which is displayed inline. That will cause that space to occur. I have redid your jsFiddle with proper alignment.

To fix it, I added the class "stuck" only when the document's scrollTop position is greater than the scrollTop position of your target element.

**jsFiddle**: http://fiddle.jshell.net/pPc4V/44/

HMTL:

```
<div id="grid"> 
     <a href="#"></a>
     <a href="#"></a>
     etc...
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#grid {
    height:1000px;
    overflow:hidden;
    float:left
}
#grid > a {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 90px;
    height: 90px;
    background: deepskyblue;
}
.stuck {
    position: fixed;
    background: navy !important;

}
```

JS:

```
    $(window).on('scroll', function () {

        var $doc = $(document),
            parentElement = $('#grid'),
            childToGetStuck = parentElement.find('a:nth-child(5)');

        if ($doc.scrollTop() > childToGetStuck.scrollTop()) {
            childToGetStuck.addClass('stuck');
            //console.log($('.stuck').scrollTop())
        } else {
            childToGetStuck.removeClass('stuck');
        }

    });
```

Comment: Mhh, nope, I don't use `position:fixed` instead `relative` inasmuch I try to let the remaining elements float if the *sticked* node has changed its position. Like if you resize the window, the elements will fill the free space...